# SourceTree/raw Git clone for bad, interrupting network connection

Tags: git, connection, repository, clone, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a very, very bad network connection in one place. It tends to slow down and sometimes even goes off for 5-10 minutes.
I am currently using SourceTree gui for Git client on Windows.
The Sourcetree allows me to clone existing repo on my machine, but it's not showing my any progress (how much % downloaded), and it forces me to redownload all again if my network connection is interrupted during the initial clone.
So, I ask, is there any tool, wrapper, or command for GIT or Sourcetree that will allow me to clone (and preferrably push/pull) GIT data reliably with resume on low network connection that might disconnect from time to time?

I want something that works like that:
1. I start git clone command
2. It downloads and shows % and progress
3. Network connection goes out for 10 minutes
4. It stops, but as soon as connection is back, it continues the download.